# How to make Undo and Redo for Slider Scale Value?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have code below :

```
var = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale(root, variable = var, command=self.scalfunc, from_=4, to=40, width=40,tickinterval=0,orient=VERTICAL,length=300,highlightthickness=0, background='#333333', fg='grey', troughcolor='#333333', activebackground='#1065BF')
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)
scale.place(x=SCwidth/1.2, y=SCheight/15)
```

and I have button `UNDO` and anther button `REDO`

I want when I click in that button I make the Slider Value undo or redo

Comment: There are no controls for undo or redo in `Scale` object. I have developed a program that implements this and will post it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code enables the use of Control keys to change the `master` colors of a `tkinter.tk` window.

Changes to `Scale` are stored in list called memory using index `int` called counter.

`Control-z` will undo

`Control-Z` will redo

`Control-x` will clear the memory

It shouldn't be too difficult to modify it for your needs.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class UndoRedo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.color = 15790320 # #f0f0f0 = SystemButtonFace
        self.var = tk.IntVar(self.master, value = self.color)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, anchor = tk.E)
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
        self.clear() # define memory and counter
        self.scroll = tk.Scale(
            self.master, orient = "horizontal", resolution = 65793,
            label = "Brightness Control", from_ = 0, to = 16777215,
            variable = self.var, command = self.control)
        self.scroll.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.EW)
        for k, v in [
            ( "<Control-z>", self.undo ),
            ( "<Control-Z>", self.redo ),
            ( "<Control-x>", self.clear )]:

            self.master.bind(k, v)
        self.master.geometry("400x86")
        self.master.update()
        self.master.minsize(329, 86)
        self.master.resizable(True, False)
        self.master.deiconify()

    def display(self):
        col = "#" + ("000000" + hex(self.color)[2:])[~5:]
        self.var.set(self.color)
        self.label["text"] = col
        self.master.tk_setPalette(col)
        
    def control(self, n):
        self.color = int(n)
        self.display()
        if self.color not in self.memory:
            self.memory.append(self.color)
            self.counter = self.counter + 1

    def action(self):
        self.color = self.memory[self.counter]
        self.display()

    def undo(self, ev = None):
        if self.memory:
            self.counter = max(0, self.counter - 1)
            self.action()

    def redo(self, ev = None):
        if self.memory:
            self.counter = min(len( self.memory ) - 1, self.counter + 1)
            self.action()

    def clear(self, ev = None):
        self.memory, self.counter = [], 0
        self.label["text"] = "cleared"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bright = UndoRedo()
    bright.master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,,, but the Question now is ,, if I have more than slider and each slider have different value ,, how I could Undo or Redo?

Comment: To do that you could create the main window separately and place all slider components into a specific class then initialize each slider. They would all have their own undo\redo control structure and memory.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could store all positions taken by the slider in a list and use an index pointer to manipulate where it is in the list.

```
silder_ind = 0
slider_positions = [4] # Or wherever you want to start by default
```

When the user changes the position of the slider

```
new_pos = slider.get_current_value() # whatever the appropriate API call is to get the current value
slider_positions.append(new_pos)
slider_ind += 1
```

When the user hits undo

```
if (slider_ind - 1) >= 0:
    slider_ind -= 1
```

redo

```
if (slider_ind + 1) < len(slider_positions):
    slider_ind += 1
```

Comment: if I have more than one slider ,,and each slider have different value ,, how I can undo or redo them ,,